# Current URL path variable

Tags: templates, variables, globals

WordPress has a built-in variable `$pagename` that will give the current page. I am looking for something that will give the full url including the path before the current page. Details below.

I am using a page template to display a folders contents depending on which page someone is on. Right now this method is working for top level paths, but not for anything nested. I understand why it isn't working, but I am not sure how to fix it. Here is an example of what I am doing now:

`$dir = "wp-content/uploads/Docs/".$pagename;`

So that will give me the correct path to the top level pages, but anything below them will not work. I know the easy solution would just to keep all folders at the base level in the upload directory, but I want my server side files to make sense also. How a url using `$pagename` looks now:

`example.com/accounting`

But lets say that I have a page within /accounting like this:

`example.com/accounting/accounts-receivable`

Using the `$pagename` method will only provide me with this:

`example.com/accounts-receivable`

My preferred solution would be to use something like `$pagename` and get the full path. I have looked in the Codex for a solution, but I am either not seeing it or it is not in there. I am specifically looked through the global variables (http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) to see if there is one. In that Codex page they do not mention their `$pagename` variable although it does exist. Hopefully there is a similar variable for the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just get the permalink and strip the home root from it-

```
$path = substr( get_permalink(), strlen( home_url('/') ) );
```

Comment: Thank you. Not enough rep for an upvote, but I appreciate it.